# Microsoft Graph API Beta - Get Chat returns 401 Unauthorized

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, http-status-code-401, unauthorized, microsoft-graph-teams

I am testing [Get Chat Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/graph/api/chat-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) (which is still in Beta) and it seems to work successfully when it is called from [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer/preview) (which uses an user token), instead when I call this API from Postman with an application token, I get `401 Unauthorized` with an `Unknown Error` as response.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/<user-id>/chats/<conversation-id>
```

My App Registration on Azure has these permissions:
[image]
And the decoded application token contains:

- "aud": "https://graph.microsoft.com",
- "roles": ["User.Read.All",    "Chat.Read.All"  ]

The same token it works for the Get User API

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/<user-id>
```

Basically, it seems to have problems only the GET Chat API when called with an application token, although the documentation says it is supported. Am I missing something in the App Registration configuration?

**EDIT**

As I have already explained in the comments, this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47870502/microsoft-graph-401-unauthorized-with-access-token) doesn't help me, since:

- audit is correct
- permissions are present in the token and are granted by the admin in the App registration
- scope is correct
  [image]

Should I check something else?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Microsoft Graph 401 Unauthorized with access token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47870502/microsoft-graph-401-unauthorized-with-access-token)

Comment: No, I have already seen that question, but it didn't help me. My audit is correct, my scope is `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default` and I have the requested permissions (of type Application) granted by the Admin.  Should I check something else?

Comment: Only delegated permission is supported for chat request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you seen this message on the (English) [documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chat-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http)?

> Before calling this API with **application permissions**, you must request access. For details, see [Protected APIs in Microsoft Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-protected-apis).

It seems like Microsoft has implemented an extra layer of security for apps accessing "Teams" endpoints.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that warning! My fault, I will do that. Thanks.

Comment: @user2297037 Could you fix this?, I have the same problem and I already have access to Protected APIs.

Comment: I finally used `Chat.Read` permission and not `Chat.Read.All` with Delegated Permission type.